# Why double (*p)[][] cannot be a valid argument while in one dimensional array double (*p)[n] and double (*p)[] can work?

Tags: c, arrays, function, arguments

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print3(int n, double (*p)[]);
void print2(int n, double (*p)[n]);
void print1(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n]);
int main(void)
{
    double a[3][2] = {{11.11, 12.12}, {21.21, 22.22}, {31.31, 32.32}};
    print1(3, 2, &a);

    double b[3] = {1234.5, 2234.5, 3234.5};
    print2(3, &b);
    print3(3, &b);

    return 0;
}
void print1(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%lf~~~", (*p)[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
void print2(int n, double (*p)[n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%lf~~~", (*p)[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
void print3(int n, double (*p)[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%lf~~~", (*p)[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Look at the above code.

I have written three functions: print1, print2, print3

Here is the output:

```
11.110000~~~12.120000~~~
21.210000~~~22.220000~~~
31.310000~~~32.320000~~~
1234.500000~~~2234.500000~~~3234.500000~~~
1234.500000~~~2234.500000~~~3234.500000~~~
```

print2 and print3 are exactly the same.

So I think both **double (*p)[n]** and **double (*p)[]** can be used as C function arguments.

However, after I remove m and n in **double (*p)[m][n]** , the program fails to be compiled.

So what confuses me is : Why **double (*p)[][]** cannot be a valid argument while in one dimensional array **double (*p)[n]** and **double (*p)[]** can work ?

Comment: You can omit the first dimension, i.e. `double (*p)[][n]`.  You can't omit the second because it's needed to determine the the multiplier for the first dimension when indexing into it (draw a picture of the array and you'll immediately see why).

Comment: You should post the code that doesn't work, not post the code that does work

Comment: @TomKarzes That's an over-simplification. This has nothing to do with "multipliers" but with the concept of incomplete array type. It has everything to do with C syntax and nothing to do with application logic.

Comment: I found a duplicate. The answer to the question why `double (*p)[][]` doesn't work but `double (*p)[]` does is not at all trivial.

Comment: @Lundin My comment provides the intuition for why leaving out the second dimension would prevent the compiler from generating code to access elements of the array.  It provides a deeper understanding for *why* the language imposes such restrictions.  Specifically, why incomplete types are not allowed as array elements.